# List mean and standard deviation

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list indexk (`in=Head[indexk]` `out=List`)
its dimensions (`in=Dimensions[indexk]` `out={3256}`)
its third element  (`in=indexk[[3]]` `out={50,1}`)

But when I attempted to get its mean  (`in=Mean[indexk]`

```
out=Mean: Rectangular array expected at position 1 in
Mean[{{49,1},{48,1},{50,1},{47,1}.....<<3206>>}]
```

```
in=Mean[index[[4,All]]]
```

```
out=24
```

```
Indexk[[1;;5,All,All]]
```

```
out={{Integer[],integer[]},{integer[],integer[]},...}
```

Would appreciate any advice on how to obtain the mean and standard deviation of this List.

Thanks,
zmm

Comment: I suspect your list doesn't have the structure you think it has. For example, list = {{49, 1}, {48, 1}, {50, 1}, {47, 1}, {25, 2}}; Mean[list] works fine.

Comment: Your list must be ragged. If it was a list of pairs, then Dimensions would return two dimensions (e.g. `{3256, 2}`). Check the results of `Dimensions /@ indexk`

Comment: It might help to look at the ones that aren't pairs via `Cases[indexk, Except[{_Integer, _Integer}]]` to see what went wrong.

Comment: You can use `GroupBy[indexk, Length]` to identify elements in the list with abnormal lengths.